# Consulta Linq en un endpoint, ¿Que sintaxis es?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, linq-to-sql, endpoint

## Pregunta original

Muy buena noche.

Estoy tratando de devolver en un endpoint la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT  G_Proyectos.Nombre AS Proyecto,
                E.Nombre AS Estado,
                COUNT(A.EstadoID) AS Cantidad
                --A.ProyectoID AS [Codigo Proyecto],
FROM     G_Actividades AS A 
                INNER JOIN G_Estados AS E 
                    ON A.EstadoID = E.EstadoID 
                INNER JOIN G_Proyectos 
                    ON A.ProyectoID = G_Proyectos.ProyectoId 
GROUP BY A.EstadoID, 
                    E.Nombre, 
                    A.ProyectoID, 
                    G_Proyectos.Nombre, 
                    A.ProyectoID, 
                    G_Proyectos.Nombre
ORDER BY Cantidad
```

El endpoint es el siguiente:

```
app.MapGet("/Grafica", async (GraficaContext context) =>
{

    return await context.GActividades.Select(b => new ProyectoResponse
    {
        Estado = b.Estado.Nombre,
        Cantidad = b.EstadoId
    }).ToListAsync();
});
```

He intentado traducir a linq la consulta de la siguiente manera, pero me devuelve el número de caracteres:

```
var estados = from a in context.GActividades
                  join e in context.GEstados
                   on a.EstadoId equals e.EstadoId
                  join p in context.GProyectos
                   on a.ProyectoId equals p.ProyectoId
                  select e.Nombre.Distinct().Count();
```

En resumen:

- Se que no estoy haciendo bien el count en la consulta de linq.
- Por lo que busque, creo que la consulta del endpoint es linq de método o algo así.
- No quiero tomar el camino fácil, de hacer una tabla temporal que se llene por medio de un paquete al momento de generar la gráfica, con los datos de la consulta.

Lo que he mirado hasta el momento es lo siguiente:

- [Method-Based Query Syntax Examples: Join (LINQ to DataSet)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/method-based-query-syntax-examples-join-linq-to-dataset)
- [Realizar combinaciones internas](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins)

Espero puedan ayudarme dándome algún consejo o material de lectura.

Feliz madrugada a todo el que pase por aquí.

## Feedback 1

Antes de agregar los modelos de ProyectoResponse, GActividades,GEstados y GProyectos, comparto la consulta que arme:

```
var ConsultaTest = (from est in context.GEstados
                 join act in context.GActividades
                 on est.EstadoId equals act.EstadoId
                 into est_act
                 from EA in est_act.DefaultIfEmpty()

                 from act in context.GActividades
                 join pro in context.GProyectos
                 on act.ProyectoId equals pro.ProyectoId
                 into act_pro
                 from AP in act_pro.DefaultIfEmpty()

                 select new
                 {
                     Proyecto = AP.Nombre,
                     Estado = EA.Estado.Nombre,
                     EstadoID = EA.EstadoId
                 }
                 );
```

Dándome la siguiente colección.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Modelos solicitados

#### ProyectoResponse

```
namespace BackendGrafica.Models.Response
{
    public class ProyectoResponse
    {
        public string Estado { get; set; }
        public int Cantidad { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### GActividades

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BackendGrafica.Models
{
    public partial class GActividade
    {
        public GActividade()
        {
            GActividadesDets = new HashSet<GActividadesDet>();
        }

        public int ActividadId { get; set; }
        public string? Nombre { get; set; }
        public string? Descripcion { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaComienzo { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaFinal { get; set; }
        public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
        public int EstadoId { get; set; }
        public int CriticidadId { get; set; }
        public int ProyectoId { get; set; }
        public string? UsuarioActualizacion { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaActualizacion { get; set; }
        public string? UsuarioOperacion { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaOperacion { get; set; }

        public virtual GCriticidade Criticidad { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual GEstado Estado { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual GProyecto Proyecto { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual GUsuario Usuario { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ICollection<GActividadesDet> GActividadesDets { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### GEstados

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BackendGrafica.Models
{
    public partial class GEstado
    {
        public GEstado()
        {
            GActividades = new HashSet<GActividade>();
            GProyectos = new HashSet<GProyecto>();
        }

        public int EstadoId { get; set; }
        public string? Nombre { get; set; }
        public string? UsuarioActualizacion { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaActualizacion { get; set; }
        public string? UsuarioOperacion { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaOperacion { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<GActividade> GActividades { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<GProyecto> GProyectos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### GProyectos

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BackendGrafica.Models
{
    public partial class GProyecto
    {
        public GProyecto()
        {
            GActividades = new HashSet<GActividade>();
        }

        public int ProyectoId { get; set; }
        public string? Nombre { get; set; }
        public string? HistoriaCliente { get; set; }
        public decimal? Presupuesto { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaInicio { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaFin { get; set; }
        public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
        public int EstadoId { get; set; }
        public int CriticidadId { get; set; }
        public int GrupoId { get; set; }
        public string? UsuarioActualizacion { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaActualizacion { get; set; }
        public string? UsuarioOperacion { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaOperacion { get; set; }

        public virtual GCriticidade Criticidad { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual GEstado Estado { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual GGrupo Grupo { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual GUsuario Usuario { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ICollection<GActividade> GActividades { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## Feedback2

Ok tengo la consulta casi como quiero, la pase a una lista.

Sé que lo tengo que hacer es una expresión Lambda pero considero que aprenderlo en Linq me ayudara para lo siguiente.

Lo único que me falta hacer en la consulta es hacer un count para saber cuántas veces se repite el EstadoID siempre con su group by. Por ejemplo el estado ID se repite 2 veces.

```
var Vista = (from est in context.GEstados
                 join act in context.GActividades
                 on est.EstadoId equals act.EstadoId
                 into est_act
                 from EA in est_act.DefaultIfEmpty()

                 select new
                 {
                     Proyecto = EA.Proyecto.Nombre,
                     ProyectoId = EA.ProyectoId,
                     Estado = EA.Estado.Nombre,
                     EstadoID = EA.EstadoId
                 }
                 ).ToList();
```

[image: Valor de la lista]

## FeedBack 3

Respecto a la pregunta sobre el resultado de la consulta sobre la columna COUNT(A.EstadoID), le comparto el resultado en SQL Server:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que ya casi lo tengo, e modificado lo siguiente dentro del Endpoint:

```
return await context.GActividades.Select(b => new ProyectoResponse
    {
        Estado = b.Estado.Nombre,
        Cantidad = (from c in context.GActividades where c.EstadoId.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(b.EstadoId)) select c.EstadoId).Count()
    }).ToListAsync();
```

El resultado en mi Json es el siguiente:

```
[
{
"estado": "Pendiente",
"cantidad": 1
},
{
"estado": "En proceso",
"cantidad": 1
},
{
"estado": "Finalizado",
"cantidad": 5
},
{
"estado": "Finalizado",
"cantidad": 5
},
{
"estado": "Finalizado",
"cantidad": 5
},
{
"estado": "Finalizado",
"cantidad": 5
},
{
"estado": "Finalizado",
"cantidad": 5
}
]
```

Como se puede ver, las cantidades ya están siendo contadas correctamente, solo falta eliminar las repeticiones de los estados.

Por lo que probare hacer lo mismo que hice en la cantidad, una consulta declarativa para llenar el valor del atributo de la clase ProyectoResponse.

## Feedback 4

@Yussef Lo que intento llenar es la siguiente grafica de charJS, el campo del Proyecto_ID lo quiero enviar, para hacer una de las siguientes dos opciones:

1. Filtrarlo en la data del chart en su JS
2. Enviar el ID del proyecto al API para filtrarlo, cosa que aún no sé cómo enviar un parámetro al API que tengo.

En la imagen puedes ver el estado actual de la gráfica.

[image: Actividades por estados]

---

## Feedback 5#

- **@Yossef**: Muy buena respuesta la verdad me despejo varias dudas.
- **@David081**: Me parece buena idea considerar el tema del rendimiento, por el momento esperare a tener una cantidad de datos considerable para hacer una prueba, lo único que se me ocurre aparte de es hacer una prueba con selenium, o algo similar.

Les comparto como quedo al final

### EndPoint

Asíncrono con LinQ

```
app.MapGet("/GraficaBarrasEstado/{id}", async (int? id, GraficaContext ctx) =>
{
    var proyecto = ctx.GProyectos.Find(id);
    if (proyecto == null) return null;

    var Estados = await (from a in ctx.GActividades
                  where a.ProyectoId == id
                  group a by a.Estado.Nombre into A
                  orderby A.Key
                  select new ProyectoResponse()
                  {
                      Estado = A.Key ?? "",
                      Cantidad = A.Count()
                  }).ToListAsync();
    return Estados;
});
```

#### Json Resultado

```
[
{
"estado": "En proceso",
"cantidad": 1
},
{
"estado": "Finalizado",
"cantidad": 5
},
{
"estado": "Pendiente",
"cantidad": 1
}
]
```

#### Grafica resultante

Aunque me gustaría ordenarlo por el EstadoID, pero como el orderby es A.KEY, intente ponerle algo así como A.EstadoID, pero no funciono.

[image: Grafica desordenada]

### Falta

Ahora solo me falta tomar el ID del proyecto, del que se me ocurre tomarlo de las siguientes dos formas:

1. Desde la vista con

   var ProyectoID = Model.ProyectoId;
2. En el archivo JS, recortando el ultimo valor de la dirección web.

Comment: Favor agrega el modelo de ProyectoResponse, GActividades,GEstados y GProyectos

Comment: Para responder la pregunta del título. La sintaxis del endpoins se llama Lambda Epression

Comment: @Yussef ahorita lo agregó, y está bien son Lambda.

Comment: @Yussef ahora que sé que son Lambda voy a ver como se hacen. También compartí la consulta que hice ahorita, con una imagen del valor que lleva, pero no entiendo porque me dio cuatro tuplas en lugar de 1 por tupla. También en el debugview me aparece la expresión y el query, no sé si la expresión está en lambda también.

Comment: Estimado estaba viendo su código pero tengo una duda, usted hace en SQL COUNT(A.EstadoID) AS Cantidad, pero según su modelo una actividad tiene una relación n a 1 con proyectos, es decir una actividad tiene un solo proyecto asociado, por lo que el COUNT(A.EstadoID) siempre es 1....o me equivoco??

Comment: @Yussef, he compartido una retroalimentación #3 donde le comparto el resultado dentro de SSMS y también cómo va el Json resultante del EndPoint

Comment: Entonces, lo que tu quieres es una lista de los proyectos, con el estado correspondiente y la cantidad de actividades??

Comment: O quieres una lista de estados con la cantidad de proyectos correspondientes????

Comment: @Yussef, agregue mas feedback para explicarme mejor.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sintaxis Lambda Expression y Linq

Entity Framework transforma tus datos en Objetos y colecciones de objetos, luego estas colecciones las puedes consultar usando Lambda o Linq. En el resultado final no tienen diferencia de rendimientos, pues al compilarlos dan el mismo código.
Además puedes combinar ambos

2. El uso de los JOINS

Aquí es donde Entity Framework se gana el premio. Tu tablas relacionadas no necesitan un join explicito, ya que la relación está dada por el modelo. Tú puedes navegar hacia las tablas hijas, tal como recorres propiedades, ejemplo: tabla1.hija.nieta

Aquí hay 2 modelos a seguir

- Lazzy Loading
- Eager Loading

Con la primera opción siempre traes las tablas y objetos hijos, con la segunda debes declarar explícitamente que quieres que te traiga (usando Include).

Según tus ejemplo, veo que tienes configurado la primera opción, así que yo voy a usarlo de esa manera

3. La consulta

La verdad, no entiendo bien lo que intentas hacer. Pero para poder tener un punto de referencia, voy a suponer que intentas graficar la cantidad de actividades según su estado, de un proyecto en particular.

Versión Linq

```
app.MapGet("/Grafica/{id}", (int id, GraficaContext context) =>
{
    var proyecto = context.GProyectos.Find(id);
    if(proyecto == null) return null;

    return from a in proyecto.GActividades
                group a by a.Estado into A
                select new ProyectoResponse()
                {
                    Estado = A.Key.Nombre??"",
                    Cantidad = A.Count()
                };

});
```

Versión Lambda

```
app.MapGet("/Grafica/{id}", (int id, GraficaContext context) =>
{
    var proyecto = context.GProyectos.Find(id);
    if(proyecto == null) return null;

    return proyecto.GActividades.GroupBy(a => a.Estado)
               .Select(a => new ProyectoResponse() { Estado = a.Key.Nombre, Cantidad = a.Count() });

});
```

Comment: estoy revisando lo que me has compartido, por el momento me regresa un json vacío, pero veo que usas un group by para sacar la lista de estados.

Comment: @VICENTEGEOVANNYFRANCOSILES me avisas cualquier cosa. Creo que al principio estaba confundido porque miraba el estado de proyectos, no me había dado cuenta que actividades también tiene estado. Favor verifica que "proyecto" no sea null, quizás por ahí te retorna lo vacío, si es así, es que la id que se pasa por parámetro no es correcta.

Comment: @Yussef estimado, es una buena respuesta, tengo una duda con respecto a querys pesadas (con un monton de tablas involucradas), cual opcion seria mas conveniente? linq? EF?, refiriendonos a rendimiento y velocidad de respuesta.

Comment: @David081 Entity Framewor convierte tu consulta Linq o Lambda en una consulta SQL, luego el resultado de dicha consulta la convierte en objeto C#. Estas conversiones tienen un costo marginal en comparación al costo de la consulta misma. Por lo tanto una consulta en EF es casi equivalente a una SQL. En mi experiencia, los problemas de performance pasan por una consulta ineficiente y es ese el primer punto a atacar, en general no hay una receta única, ya que cada problema es diferente. Luego de haber creado la mejor consulta posible debes pasar a las optimizaciones de tracking y de plan chaché

Comment: @Yussef respecto si el proyecto esta null, el unico ID de proyecto asignado a la actividad se encuentra en 1, por lo que entrando al url del enpoint con ese parametro me retorna un [], si le ingreso cualquier otro me regresa un null.

Comment: @Yussef también es buena idea considerar el rendimiento, pero para probar las respuestas desde el cliente debería de llenar mis tablas con mínimo 1000 registros y de allí ir tomando muestras en los tiempos de respuesta en el cliente. Pero considero que luego de tener unos 25 proyectos con 20 actividades en promedio cada uno, y que se mantengan 5 estados y 5 criticidades, ya se podría comenzar a hacer pruebas de ese tipo.

Comment: @David081 respecto al proceso de traducciones que explicas [Linq → Lambda → SQL], me pregunto será mejor utilizar Lambda ya que así se va eliminando intermediarios, por lo que considero que esto eliminaría tiempo de ejecución al momento de traducir.